# Setenv in /etc/launchd.conf not taking whole string in OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, terminal, environment-variables, setenv

Hey I'm wondering if there is a constraint on using setenv to setup environment variables in OSX Mavericks? I have the following setup in /etc/launchd.conf:

```
setenv CLASSPATH .:/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/..... (More paths here. In total 6557 characters long)
```

What I'm finding is on start up the environment variable $CLASSPATH is only saving a fraction of the string. Only 982 characters in the string are being saved.

If anyone has any knowledge of how to fix this it would be much appreciated. I'm getting sick of exporting CLASSPATH=path every time I open a terminal window. Thanks!

Comment: You could always `setenv CLASSPATH <someshortenoughvalue>`, then on the next line `setenv CLASSPATH $CLASSPATH:<someothervalue>` etc etc. But do you really use csh? Also, no spaces or the like in the string?

Comment: I was thinking about that. I'll give it a try. Yea there is no spaces.

Comment: I'm having trouble concatenating the environment variables using setenv.